# why php mail function not work in xampp

Tags: php, email, outlook, xampp, mercury-mta

I have problem i use xampp . i want check mail form but i can't see any result .
i config Mercury/32 like this tutorial in this site :

http://system66.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-send-mail-from-localhost-with.html

i check email by outlook it's work .
i check send mail by Mercury send mail in admin panel and it's correctly work .

but i can't send email and can not recive this email by outlook when i use mail php function .

why ?

please help me

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  First, show us some code so we can see what you've tried and how to fix it.

Comment: What value does your `mail` call return

Answer (score 2):

I got it . i set this config and now i can recieve my sent email in outlook:

I just need to configure
 `D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` By default, it contains the line

```
smtp_server=mail.mydomain.com
```

I had to change it to

```
smtp_server=localhost
```

No need to configure this in the older versions of XAMPP.
The correct configuration for [mail function] in
 `D:\xampp\php\php.ini` is

> ; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with an SMTP Server like
>   Mercury 
>   `SMTP = 127.0.0.1 smtp_port = 25`
>
> ; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (1): If XAMPP is installed in a base directory
>   with spaces (e.g. c:\program filesD:\xampp) fakemail and mailtodisk do
>   not work correctly. ; XAMPP IMPORTANT NOTE (2): In this case please
>   copy the sendmail or mailtodisk folder in your root folder (e.g.
>   C:\sendmail) and use this for sendmail_path.
>
> ; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with fakemail for
>   forwarding to your mailbox (sendmail.exe in the sendmail folder)
>   `sendmail_path = "\"D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`
>
> ; XAMPP: Comment out this if you want to work with mailToDisk, It
>   writes all mails in the D:\xampp\mailoutput folder 
>   `; sendmail_path ="D:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"`

Now, I'm receiving mails in my inbox. Please note that "D:\xampp\" is my XAMPP installation path.

Thanks to all friends

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to call your ISP and ask them for the smtp out server address. Once done, You need to configure you SMTP settings in C:xampp\php\php.ini file or you can add the following line at the beginning of your php script.

ini_set("SMTP","yoursmtpoutgoingserver");

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your SMTP server settings in the php.ini file

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; "http://php.net/smtp"
SMTP = localhost
; "http://php.net/smtp-port"
smtp_port = 25
```

if you don't run a mailserver locally, you will need to access a remote one like your isp or gmail

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = mail.yourserver.com
smtp_port = 25
auth_username = smtp-username
auth_password = smtp-password
sendmail_from = you@yourserver.com
```

Comment: We use Outlook for email client. So just get the outlook information and plug it in. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, hope it will help you:

1. Edit your php.ini (xampp\php\php.ini). Search for [mail function]  and change these parameters accordingly.
2. SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
3. smtp_port = 587
4. sendmail_from = [your_gmail_username]@gmail.com
           Note: this gmail account will be used to send the email
5. sendmail_path = “\”D:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\” -t”
               Note: I did install my xampp at D:\xampp
6. Edit your sendmail.ini (xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini)

Comment the “Mercury”  and “A free mail service example” contents as shown below:
   # Mercury 
   #account Mercury
   #host localhost
   #from postmaster@localhost
   #auth off
   # A freemail service 
   #account Hotmail
   #tls on
   #tls_certcheck off
   #host smtp.live.com
   #from [exampleuser]@hotmail.com
   #auth on
   #user [exampleuser]@hotmail.com
   #password [examplepassword]

1. Add the account through which you want to send your mails. In my example I have configured the Gmail account as shown below:

   1. account Gmail
2. tls on
3. tls_certcheck off
4. host smtp.gmail.com
5. from [your_gmail_username]@gmail.com
6. auth on
7. user [your_gmail_username]@gmail.com
8. password [your_gmail_password]
9. port 587

   1. Set the default account to Gmail as shown below:

   account default : Gmail