# Why is my mail function not working in XAMMP?

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have been trying to make this work using XAMPP and for some reason the mail function does not work, here is my code. I'm in a MAC and my php.ini in the etc folder and I don't have the sendmail folder.

```
$_POST['email'];

$result = mail('someEmail@gmail.com', 'This is a Subject', 'This is the body of the email', 'From: $email');
echo $result ? 'Sent' : 'Error';
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890226/why-php-mail-function-not-work-in-xampp

Comment: Thanks for the link Gustavo but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can`t directly from localhost. One way is to move your code to public server or using some SMTP server if you want to work on your localhost.
You should make some changes to those two files *xampp\php\php.ini* and *xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini*

in *php.ini* file search and  find [mail function] and make it look like this

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
sendmail_from = YOUR_MAIL@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

now in *sendmail.ini* make sure it look like this

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=YOUR_MAIL@gmail.com
auth_password=YOUR_MAIL_PASS
force_sender=YOUR_MAIL@gmail.com
```

Now make sure in *php.ini*

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

is uncommented. Also make sure to comment following line if there is another sendmail_path

```
sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"
```

If everything is OK your will be sending mail from localhost using google gmail. So the receiver will see your gmail in *FROM* field

Comment: does it matter that I'm in a MAC?

Comment: No, i suppose. Just the paths to/in your .ini files may be different.

Comment: My php.ini is in the etc folder but I can't find the sendmail folder anywhere. By the way I tried my live server and the original mail function I posted does not either.

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRJSQjXGjOA) may be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks Petko and friends, All I had to do was to set the path in the sendmail_path, even though I never got an email, the mail() error went away and it said sent :)

Answer (score 0):

The email function will work correctly when you upload this code to a server, and sends email to the user.

try this code, that works perfectly when put into a file on the server:

```
<?php
$to = "xyz@somedomain.com";
$subject = "This is subject";
$message = "This is simple text message.";
$header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
$retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if( $retval == true )  
{
  echo "Message sent successfully...";
}
else
{
  echo "Message could not be sent...";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried and it does not work!