# how to send email in codeigniter on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

hello all i have to send email on localhost
and following is my config file

```
$config['useragent']      = "CodeIgniter";
$config['mailpath']       = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i";
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'xyz.com'; //change this
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'xyz.com'; //change this
$config['smtp_pass'] = '######'; //change this
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes to comply with RFC 822 standard
```

i create code follwing code for email send

```
if(count($result) > 0 || $result != NULL){
                    $password=$result['password'];
                    $this->load->library('email');
                    $from='chirag@site.com';
                    $to=$email;
                    $subject='forget password';                        
                    $this->email->from($from);
                    $this->email->to($to);
                    $this->email->subject($subject);
                    $this->email->message($password);
                    if($this->email->send()){
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('email','We sent your password to your Email...!');
                        redirect('login');
                    }
                    else{            
                        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
                    }
            }
```

but i got following error when i send email

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

so what is problem there? 
please help me to solve

Comment: Are your host / user / pass valid (sure about that) and where is the code which try to send email..?

Comment: yes all are valid host,user,pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you already done the proper localhost configuration for [sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31299895/5094931).
Then in your controller you load the email library by setting the appropriate credentials and port number. Like so:

```
$config = Array(
                            'protocol' => 'smtp',
                            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                            'smtp_port' => 465,
                            'smtp_user' => 'your_gmail_name@gmail.com', 
                            'smtp_pass' => 'your_pass', 
                            //'mailtype' => 'html',
                            // 'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                            // 'wordwrap' => TRUE
                        );
                        $this->load->library('email', $config);
```

Answer (score 1):

i got answer 
there is missing a ssl:// in config 
but after writing following

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://xyz.com';
```

mail is send successfully...